# Are chess PSPACE-complete or PSPACE-hard only?

Tags: computational-complexity, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, chessboard

There are [links](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-that-the-chess-game-is-a-PSPACE-complete-problem-the-hardest-kind-of-problems-in-PSPACE-complexity-class) that claim that chess are PSPACE-complete but the snippet below from the Handbook of theoretical computer science says that they are harder. Which statement is true ??
[image]

**EDIT: included refrences 33,98,99**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you read the papers [33,98,99], seen their precise claims, and compared with what is claimed in the Storer paper?  You might find there is no conflict after all.  In particular, to discuss any sort of complexity, one has to generalize the game of chess to boards of arbitrary size, and it could be that the papers do this in non-equivalent ways.

Comment: But at the very least, you could include in your question the bibliographic details of  the papers [33,98,99], so that those who do not have the book could still try to look up the papers.

Comment: @NateEldredge References included.